# C# How can I communicate between winfirms app and unity android app?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project for my friend and I need to implement communication between windows forms app and unity android app but I don't know how. Example of my code:

**Unity:**

```
Class program
{

   Public InputField password;

   Public static void Loggin ()
   {

      String localpass = password.text;

      String winpass = //passS from WinForm code

      If (localpass == winpass)
         Mytextbox.text = "success";
      Else
         Mytextbox.text = "wrong password";

   }

}
```

**WinForm:**

```
Public static void myVoid ()
{

   String passS = File.ReadLines(App domain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\\mytextfile.txt").ElementAtOrDefault(3);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Direct communication

Socket programming is your friend. This means that the two applications are aware of each other, or at least one of them (the client) is aware of the other (the server)

C# example of a tcp/ip listener

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Net;      //required
using System.Net.Sockets;    //required

namespace ServerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 9999);  
           // we set our IP address as server's address, and we also set the port: 9999

            server.Start();  // this will start the server

            while (true)   //we wait for a connection
            {
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();  //if a connection exists, the server will accept it

                NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream(); //networkstream is used to send/receive messages

                byte[] hello = new byte[100];   //any message must be serialized (converted to byte array)
                hello = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("hello world");  //conversion string => byte array

                ns.Write(hello, 0, hello.Length);     //sending the message

                while (client.Connected)  //while the client is connected, we look for incoming messages
                {
                    byte[] msg = new byte[1024];     //the messages arrive as byte array
                    ns.Read(msg, 0, msg.Length);   //the same networkstream reads the message sent by the client
                    Console.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(msg).Trim('')); //now , we write the message as string
                }
            }
```

### Create an api to communicate

The options are unlimited. Create a rest api using WebApi 2 or any other technology to periodically hit and check for data updates.

This communication is asynchronous and not direct,  so you should account for that in some way.

### Use push notifications

Mobile applications can get push notifications. If the communication is not bidirectional, this on its own could be a solution.

If it is, then the mobile application could communicate via an api and the forms application via push notifications

Check https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/157009/how-can-i-send-android-notifications-from-my-unity-game#

Comment: It seems very complicated but I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. If you are only communicating locally. Try socket programming, Use TCP/IP for communication between the two programs.

Try this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-c-sharp/) for a start

Or if you want to connect over a network try WCF can also work out

Try this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/basic-wcf-service-step-by-step/) for a WCF fresh start (this is Slower)

or you can use SignalR web sockets

Try this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for ASP NET CORE SignalR

Another way is to use RabbitMQ

Try this [link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) for RabbitMQ documentation

And there many more ways.

Comment: Try not to use WCF as it has been retired by Microsoft.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel can you refer a link to me for the wcf retired news

Comment: It won't be ported to .Net Core 3 and later versions. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-is-the-future-of-net/

Comment: Yes clearly WCF won't be in the NET Core 3 but its still a viable option on how the OP can solve the problem he is facing.